# Why check concurrent modifications when iterating thread-unsafe collections?

Tags: java, concurrency

The fail-fast mechanism for checking the concurrent modification in synchronized collections is reasonable, since these collections are considered thread-safe in multi-threads environment and thus they should be aware of the concurrent modification.

But I'm confused why those thread-unsafe collections like `ArrayList` which should work in single-thread environment also need to be aware of the concurrent modification in iteration?

Thanks for your reply in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't mistake the "concurrent" in "concurrent modification" as referring only to multithreading.

You can get a ConcurrentModificationException in single-threaded code too:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add("");
Iterator<String> it = list.iterator();
list.add("");
it.next(); // ConcurrentModificationException
```

Comment: Note that these mechanisms can *sometimes* also detect multi-threaded modifications, but that's not guaranteed. Concurrent modifications in a single thread are more reliably detected (but still not guaranteed in the general case).

Comment: @JoachimSauer indeed. As is noted in the Javadoc, the CME indicates the presence of a bug, but its absence does not indicate the absence of a bug.

Comment: Thanks! But I wonder why adding elements to underlying collection is not allowed after creating the iterator, even when the iteration and the adding operations are in the same thread(So the underlying collection should not be corrupted)?   Is this because the iteration should be considered as a "atomic" operation that when an iteration begins, the underlying collection should not be changed by outside actions, no matter which thread the change occurs in

Comment: @folkboat it's a question of how the iterator should handle the change. If the insertion is after the current point in the iteration, is it obviously correct to include that in the elements returned by the iterator? If the insertion or deletion is at a point that the iterator has already passed, is it obviously correct to keep the iterator "where it was" (in terms of the index in the list; or in terms of between the same two elements)? Whichever way you silently ignore/handle it, it would have surprising behaviour.

Comment: @folkboat The explanation can be found in the documentation of `ArrayList`: `The iterators returned by this class's iterator and listIterator methods are fail-fast [...] Thus, in the face of concurrent modification, the iterator fails quickly and cleanly, rather than risking arbitrary, non-deterministic behavior at an undetermined time in the future.`